# How can I make rails.js re-apply the same magic to new forms that are loaded dynamically?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

For my understanding rails.js do some magic to my forms (that have ":remote => true") to transform them into ajax form once the page is loaded.

When one of these forms is submitted, it is replaced with a new form.

How can I make rails.js re-apply the same magic to this new form?

Comment: What versions of rails and jquery-rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The [current rails unobstrusive javascript jQuery adapter](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/c00a9726837756ea53404ca7e8b0f12df19a6496/src/rails.js) appears to handle the forms added after the page load just fine, using the `live` jQuery function.